# Same simple source code, different binaries on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, compilation, binary

I have a question about the source-code binary on Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The same source code, I compiled twice on Windows (VS 2008 Cmmand Prompt: "CL"), but I got different binaries.

```
cl new.cpp
```

Can you guys tell me why, and how to avoid that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221185/identical-build-on-different-systems and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277877/gcc-compiled-binaries-w-different-sizes - basically no compiler guarantees binaries will be identical.

Comment: Why do you need the binaries to be identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timestamp is part of PE format. You'll always get different values regardless if compiling as release or not.

Comment: How can I avoid that? Is it possible to remove the timestamp? Because in Linux, if I use g++/gcc, the final binaries are the same.

Comment: @Peter: ELF (Linux's executable format) does not have a timestamp field. Why does it matter if the output is different?

Comment: @Billy: You are right that ELF might not have the timestamp field. It's just very annoying that same source code different binaries.

Comment: @Peter: Why is that annoying?

Comment: The only problem I see from this is if you're trying to debug a crash dump (aka core dumps). Windows debugging tools associate the dump with a binary checksum, so you can't debug the dump with a different binary, even if there is no code changes. Some tools can update the checksum in the dump file but usually this is not a good idea. BTW, I have no idea how does this work on Unix world.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile as release?  Debug has timestamps built in which can change your exe per compile

Comment: Compiling as directed above yielded a difference of exactly 1 byte.  The LSB of the embedded timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I googled, and found a mid-way solution:

```
DUMPBIN  /RAWDATA  MyApp.EXE > first.txt
DUMPBIN  /RAWDATA  MyApp.EXE > second.txt
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164151
How to compare binary images of the same project builds

Comment: You could also work around it by setting the timestamp to the same value in both executables.